# How to change the id only for the newly inserted object without affecting the object with the same initial id that's already inside the array?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to implement react-beautiful-dnd in my app and I'm running into an issue when I try to drag the component of the same type into the droppable area more than once.
In the state I'm importing an array of objects that contain properties of all the available dragable components. I also have an array of usedComponents which represents the components dragged into the droppable area.

```
import components from "../schemas/components";

class Editor extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      components: components, //array of all available components
      usedComponents: [
        components[0],
        components[2],
        components[7],
        components[8],
        components[9],
        components[10],
        components[11],
        components[12] //these objects are set initially
      ],
      selectedComponent: null,
    };
  }
}
```

component objects look something like this:

```
{
  id: 1,
  group: "header",
  componentType: "headerLogo",
  componentName: "Header 01",
  //...rest of the component properties
}
```

the portion of the onDragEnd handler related to adding new component that gives me trouble looks like this:

```
onDragEnd(result) {
  const { destination, source } = result;
  if (source.droppableId !== destination.droppableId) {
    //add component
    this.setState(prevState => {
      const newComponent = prevState.components.filter(
        item => item.group === source.droppableId
      )[source.index];
      let usedComponents = prevState.usedComponents;
      usedComponents.splice(destination.index + 1, 0, newComponent);

      return {
        ...prevState,
        usedComponents: usedComponents
      };
    });
  }
}
```

So, where the trouble begins is when usedComponents array already contains a component with an id say 5, and I try to drag another component with the same id into the droppable area. I have another handler that I use for selecting a component on click which is based around the component id and every time there are two or more components with the same id inside the usedComponents array, clicking on any of them selects them all, which is not a desired behavior. Each component should be selected individually, no matter if it's of the same type or not.
To remedy this I tried to change the id of the object set in const newComponent before it is inserted into the .splice() method, but no matter how I try do it, it changes both the id of the newly inserted component as well as the component of the same type (same initial id) already contained in usedComponents array. How do I change the id only for the newly inserted component without affecting the component with the same initial id already contained in usedComponents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell from your description, it sounds like you were doing something like

```
newComponent = prevState.components.filter(
        item => item.group === source.droppableId
      )[source.index];
newComponent.id = newId;
```

(where newId is whatever you want the new id to be), and then trying to insert that back into the array. Instead try using [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```js
oldComponent = prevState.components.filter(
        item => item.group === source.droppableId
      )[source.index];
newComponent = {
  ...oldComponent,
  id: newId
};
```

After that you should have a new component instead of a reference to the old component to insert into your array.

Comment: Damn, that fixed it instantly. You're a lifesaver dude. Thanks a million.